# AngularJS - Convert JSON string into HTML codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

```
        {
            author_signature: 'What is beauty if the brain is empty.',
            date_created: '2016-12-01 (16:15)',
            content: '<p>Potenti elit lectus augue eget iaculis vitae</p>',
        },
```

Could you please help me convert "**content**" into a html code when angular passed it to the view...

Currently, it returns

```
<div>" <p>Potenti elit lectus augue eget iaculis vitae</p> "</div>
```

Thanks :D

Comment: I'm not particularily versed in Angular, though from JS in general I'm assuming not escaping those spaces of yours is allowing the browser to interpret your elements as a text node, instead of parsing them.

Comment: What does your template and controller look like?